# how to integrate FIPS capable openssl library in AOSP in place of default openssl.

Tags: android, openssl, android-source, fips

a.)I am trying to make my device fips capable. I have AOSP code, can I integrate the fips capable library I generated using https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/FIPS_Library_and_Android into my aosp build?

b.)Also, I want all the sites that open to be minimum 256 bit encrypted.

Is there any way to ensure the requirement b ?